# AngularJS - How to define an initial delay for ng-bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

we have a span element which looks like this:

```
<span role="link" ng-show="showLink()" ng-bind="textLink"></span>
```

(Just as info: we have a little fade-in, fade-out animation for this link, that's why we had to use ng-show instead of ng-if)

The problem is, when the page is initially loaded, ng-bind binds the text, and just for a few miliseconds we see the link (flickering problem), then comes ng-show and showLink returns false initially, link will be hidden.

**How can we achieve this setup so that, the initial load of the page does not show the link at all?**

PS: I could of course create a function which delivers the text with a setTimeout (300ms). But i would like to see if there is a better way to do it **without timeout**.

Answer (score 2):

Bind the `ng-cloak` attribute

> The **ngCloak** directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

`<span role="link" ng-show="showLink()" ng-bind="textLink" ng-cloak></span>`

[More details from AngularJs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Comment: Does `showLink()` always returns false on initial page load?

Comment: should we see the ng-cloak attribute in the rendered html code? at the moment we do not see that.

Comment: Does showLink() always returns false on initial page load?
Yes.. also a simple "return false" does not change anything. Also ng-show="false"

Comment: No, you don't see the `ng-cloak` in the rendered html code. Alternately, you could set the style of the element to `hidden` by default if _showLink() always returns false on initial page load_

Comment: Clear the browser cache once, maybe`ng-cloak` has not set yet.

Comment: no cache problem.. but adding class ng-hide did the trick. thank you! i will post this as a separate answer..

Answer (score 0):

Just inject $timeout in your controller and use this.

```
$timeout(function() { $scope.showLink = false;}, 2000);
```

Also you can use $digest or $apply as below

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.showLink = false;
    $scope.$digest();
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function () {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.showLink = false;
  });
}, 2000);


<span role="link" ng-show="showLink" ng-bind="textLink"></span>
```

Comment: please look at the end of my question.. i explicitly wrote that i do not want a timeout..

Comment: sorry i missed that point, but you can also do it by: <input type ng-model="query" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default':
 2000, 'blur': 1 } }" />

Comment: refer this You may find thid intresting  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Answer (score 0):

i simply added the class "ng-hide" to the class attribute of my span element, and did the trick in my case..